# Trait object lifetime that matches a returning iterator's lifetime triggers a lifetime error

Tags: rust

I have a trait with a function that returns `Box<dyn Iterator<...>>`. As I understand it, based off the definition, the lifetime of this returned iterator needs to match the trait object's. But in a function that drops both at the end, I get a lifetime error. Here's a minimal example, with assumptions added as comments:

```rust
trait Foo<'a> {
    // The returned iterator's lifetime should match self's
    fn bar(&'a self) -> Box<dyn Iterator<Item = usize> + 'a>;
}

struct FooImpl {
    values: Vec<usize>
}

impl<'a> Foo<'a> for FooImpl {
    fn bar(&'a self) -> Box<dyn Iterator<Item = usize> + 'a> {
        Box::new(self.values.iter().cloned())
    }
}

fn foo_bar_caller<'a>(foo: Box<dyn Foo<'a>>) {
    // `foo` is moved into this fn
    let _iter = foo.bar();
    // `_iter` and `foo` should drop
}

fn main() {
    let foo = FooImpl { values: vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5] };
    foo_bar_caller(Box::new(foo));
}
```

([rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0ebb98c501b31f1a0d045e897d4d893c) with the code.) Running this gives the following lifetime error:

```
error[E0597]: `*foo` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:17:17
   |
16 | fn foo_bar_caller<'a>(foo: Box<dyn Foo<'a>>) {
   |                   -- lifetime `'a` defined here
17 |     let _iter = foo.bar();
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^
   |                 |
   |                 borrowed value does not live long enough
   |                 argument requires that `*foo` is borrowed for `'a`
18 |     // `_iter` and `foo` should drop
19 | }
   | - `*foo` dropped here while still borrowed

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0597`.
error: could not compile `playground` due to previous error
```

Comment: I think it would help if you saw the desugared syntax: `Foo::bar(&*foo)`.  You are creating a temporary borrow when calling the method on the trait object that is thwarting you.

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/scope/lifetime/explicit.html this kind of explains by example what is going on

Comment: You cannot annotate a longer lifetime onto a shorter reference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably meant to make the *function* `Foo::bar` generic over the reference lifetime, not the trait `Foo`:

```
trait Foo {
    // The returned iterator's lifetime should match self's
    fn bar<'a>(&'a self) -> Box<dyn Iterator<Item = usize> + 'a>;
}
```

By putting the lifetime on the trait `Foo`, you are unnecessarily (in this context, at least) restricting the lifetimes of the references you can use with a particular `Foo::<'_>::bar` implementation. A `<T as Foo<'a>>::bar` (`T` in the context of `foo_bar_caller` being `Box<dyn Foo<'a>>`) call can only take references with the lifetime `'a`, but as @MaximilianBurszley points out in the comments, what you are actually passing to it is a temporary borrow that does *not* have the same lifetime `'a`.

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9f1b226b0272589e8fddc868ecc63e01)

Note that you can make `foo_bar_caller` [work with your existing code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9dd3355e0051247c5436b7662a7e0db0) (with the *trait* `Foo` being generic over the lifetime) if you make the function take a reference with the same lifetime:

```
fn foo_bar_caller<'a>(foo: &'a dyn Foo<'a>) {
    // `foo` is moved into this fn
    let _iter = foo.bar();
    // `_iter` and `foo` should drop
}

fn main() {
    let foo = FooImpl { values: vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5] };
    foo_bar_caller(&foo);
}
```

Alternatively, you can use a [higher-ranked trait bound](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/hrtb.html) (HRTB) to specify that `foo_bar_caller` must take in a value that implements `Foo<'b>` for *all* lifetimes `'b`:

```
fn foo_bar_caller(foo: Box<dyn for<'b> Foo<'b>>) {
    // `foo` is moved into this fn
    let _iter = foo.bar();
    // `_iter` and `foo` should drop
}
```

This allows the `Foo<'_>` implementation for the value `foo` to be valid for the lifetime for the temporary borrow created during the `foo.bar()` call (since it implements `Foo<'_>` for *all* lifetimes).

[Playground for HRTB version](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ffb60c596a89261a13e45a2523460dd4)